# Is it possible to open a link in app without performing the domain verification in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I want to implement a case wherein if I click on a deeplink in android, it should direct me to the app instead of browser. Thing are working fine in Android version below 12, a dialog box appears to open the link in app or browser. But in Android 12 and above, everytime the link is opening in the browser. Is there any way to make it work without doing the domain verification as the domain that opens in browser when the link is clicked does not belong to me.

I noticed this behaviour in "signal app" which always opens the link in the app even if the device is offline, conditioned that the app is installed.

This is my manifest file code. I m trying to open the MainActivity2 through deeplink.

`

```
<application
android:name=".App"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.NotificationApp"
tools:targetApi="31">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="standard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:host="papayacoders.in"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:host="papayacoders.in"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>`
```

Comment: Hi @Vipul, Can you tell us 'How you created the deep link'?

Comment: @ShivamJamaiwar The deeplink "papayacoders.in" is not owned by me, but I want to use it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

According to the documentation, the behavior changed from Android 12. It's probably a security measure.

> Web links are deep links that use the HTTP and HTTPS schemes. On Android 12 and higher, clicking a web link (that is not an Android App Link) always shows content in a web browser. On devices running previous versions of Android, if your app or other apps installed on a user's device can also handle the web link, users might not go directly to the browser.

So you'll need to implement "App links" instead.